# How to search for all the files starting with the name "ABC" in a directory?

Tags: directory, search, regex

I need to search for files starting with some particular name. There can be multiple files starting with a particular pattern and I want to list all such files present in the directory.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

To complete existing answers:

### [`ls`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ls.1)

The default directory list utility `ls` can be used in combination with the shell's wildcards . To search for all files with pattern `abc`:

```
ls -d abc*   # list all files starting with abc---
ls -d *abc*  # list all files containing --abc--
ls -d *abc   # list all files ending with --abc
```

Note that the file extension is relevant for the search results too.

---

### [`tree`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/tree.1)

In case we need to list files in a directory tree we can also issue `tree` to search for a given [pattern](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/tree.1) like:

```
tree -P 'abc*'  # list directory tree of file starting with abc---
tree -l 'def*'  # exclude files starting with def---
```

In this case, `tree` itself supports wildcards.

Comment: Why when I do `ls -l B*` does it show the *contents* of all directories starting with `B` instead of just the names of the matching directories?

Comment: @ErikE Because when you ask `ls` to list a directory, it opens it, it's the same as doing `ls -l BirthdayPhotos`. You can suppress that behavior with `ls -d B*`.

Comment: @AzorAhai But why does it treat `B*` as a directory specification?

Comment: @ErikE Because using the file glob `B*` expands to match all directories that start with `B` so you're really passing `ls` a list of directories, so it opens them all for you.

Comment: Found `tree -P 'abc*' --prune` incredibly useful!

Comment: Does not answer the question. `ls -d ABC*` was what the author was asking about. Also comments in the code snippet are wrong, `ls abc*` lists *content* of directories starting with abc.

Answer (score 68):

You can use `find` command to search files with pattern

```
find . -type f -name "abc*"
```

The above command will search the file that starts with abc under the current working directory.

`-name 'abc'` will list the files that are exact match. Eg: abc

You can also use

```
 -iname
 -regex
```

option with `find` command to search filename using a pattern

Answer (score 9):

There are many ways to do it, depending on exactly what you want to do with them. Generally, if you want to just list them, you can do it in a terminal using:

`find | grep '^\./ABC'`

... and replacing `ABC` with your text.

To understand the command, let's break it down a bit:

- `find` lists all files under the current directory and its sub-directories; using it alone will just list everything there. Note that `find` outputs each file or directory starting with `./`, indicating that their path is relative to the current directory. Being aware of this is important because it means we will search for results starting with `./ABC` and not just `ABC`.
- The pipe character `|` redirects the output of one command to another, in this case the output of `find` is redirected to `grep`. This is called piping.
- `grep` takes the output and filters it using the given pattern, `^\./ABC`.

  - Notice that the pattern is quoted with single quotes `' '` to prevent the shell from interpreting the special characters inside it.
- Now the pattern itself is written in a particular syntax called **regular expression**, or **regex** for short. Regex is an extremely powerful searching tool if you master it, and there are sites such as [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) which teach you about it in more depth, but note that `grep` is not a full-fledged regex engine and you can't do everything with it.
- For our purpose:

  - `^` in regex matches the beginning of the string; this prevents it from matching the pattern if it doesn't occur in the beginning of the file name.
  - `.` in regex has a special meaning too: it means "match any single character here". In case you want to use it as a literal dot, you'll have to "escape" it using a backslash `\` before it. (Yeah, matching any character would be harmless in our case, but I did it for completeness' sake.)

Comment: Why would you `find | grep` when `find` has its own perfectly good pattern-matching capabilities?

Answer (score 4):

You can search for a particular pattern using the Nautilus file manager and regular expressions.

To do so, click on *Select Items Matching* in the Gear menu like below (you can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>).

[image]

Then, just type the [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) `ABC*` and validate.

[image]

Every file whose name matches your pattern will be automatically selected.

[image]

I'm using Nautilus 3.6.* from [GNOME3](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3) PPA on Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal).

Comment: this is a powerful answer. Still valid today 2021

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution to me

```
ls | grep PATTERN
```

Here you can give any regular expression in the PATTERN.

For example, to find files with "ab" anywhere within its name, type

```
ls | grep ".*ab.*"
```

To find the files starting with "ab", type

```
ls | grep "^ab"
```

Comment: it takes forever for me and i am trying to get video file names with for example (1990) 
`find . -maxdepth 1 | grep -R "\(\d\d\d\d\)"`

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know the directory the `ABC*` files are located in, and you have millions of files, the `locate` command is the fastest method.

```
$ locate /ABC
/mnt/clone/home/rick/.cache/mozilla/firefox/9fu0cuql.default/cache2/entries/ABC6AD2FEC16465049B48D39FD2FE538258F2A34
/mnt/clone/home/rick/.cache/mozilla/firefox/9fu0cuql.default/cache2/entries/ABCBFDA54262F47253F95ED6ED4131A465EE0E39
/mnt/clone/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.1-050001/tools/lib/lockdep/tests/ABCABC.sh
/mnt/clone/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.1-050001/tools/lib/lockdep/tests/ABCDBCDA.sh
/mnt/clone/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.1-050001/tools/lib/lockdep/tests/ABCDBDDA.sh
/mnt/old/home/rick/.cache/mozilla/firefox/3vkvi6ov.default/cache2/entries/ABC0C99FCEABAD0C6AA2078CD025A1CDE48D7BA1
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.1-050001/tools/lib/lockdep/tests/ABCABC.sh
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.1-050001/tools/lib/lockdep/tests/ABCDBCDA.sh
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.0.1-050001/tools/lib/lockdep/tests/ABCDBDDA.sh
```

**Notes:**

- The above command takes 1 second to run on 1 million files.
- In comparison the `find` command starting at `/` root directory will **a very long time** and generate many permission errors.
- If files were created today you must run `sudo updatedb` first.

Answer (score 3):

you can use GREP, I think this is the most simple solution, probably also add some other grep parameters to make the match more accurate

```
tree | grep ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

[Command-t](https://github.com/wincent/command-t) in one of my favorite vim plugins, it's ruby based plugin above integration with [FZF.](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf)

By using Comamnd-T and FZF you can do the search with an extremely fast "fuzzy" mechanism for:

- Opening files and buffers
- Jumping to tags and help
- Running commands, or previous searches and commands
- with a minimal number of keystrokes.

As you can see

[image]

I always search in command history by opening a new terminal and hit:

```
CTRL+R
```

In addition to searching in all folders recursively by writing in any terminal tab:

```
fzf
```

Then start your file name

```
ABC
```

Also, you can write inside `vim`

```
:CommandT
```

Really helpful especially in large folders.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
ls | grep abc
```

or

```
ls -la | grep abc
```

It show all files with abc, not just starting with abc. 
But, It's a really easy way for me for to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
$ python -c 'import sys,os;found=[os.path.join(r,i) for r,s,f in os.walk(".") for i in f if i.startswith("ABC")];map(lambda x: sys.stdout.write(x+"\n") ,found)'
```

Perl:

```
$ perl -le 'use File::Find;find(sub{ -f && $_ =~/^ABC/ && print $File::Find::name  },".")'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
printf "%s" /path/to/files/ABC*
```

This is glob pattern matching which is anchored at both ends. This will match all occurrences of files starting with "ABC" such as "ABC", "ABC.txt", "ABC123", but not "xABC". From the command line using 'ls' in place of 'printf' here is a safe alternative however, depending on who's opinion you agree with, 'ls' is not safe for use in a script. In that case using 'printf' with glob pattern matching is considered safe. If you going to use this in a script the output of 'printf' will not contain a new line character until the end of the output stream as such:

```
printf "%s" /path/to/files/ABC*
```

Returns:

```
/path/to/files/ABC /path/to/files/ABC123
```

If you need line breaks after each instance:

```
printf "%s\n" /path/to/files/ABC*
```

Returns:

```
/path/to/files/ABC 

/path/to/files/ABC123
```

"/path/to/files/" remains in the output if you entered it that way when you ran the 'printf' command. Without it just the file name appears:

```
printf "%s" ABC*
```

Returns

```
ABC ABC123
```

Assuming you run the command within the directory in which the files exist.

Comment: The `echo /path/to/files/ABC*  | tr " " "\n"` isn't a good idea. Consider if there's a file `/path/to/files/ABC EFG` , there is a space in the filename. Your `tr` will break the filename into two separate lines, which is not good. Even worse if there's multiple spaces in filename.   I'd recommend you use `printf "%s\n" ABC*` instead, which should  help with spaces in the filenames, but still is problematic with other special characters  like `\n`

Answer (score 0):

Assume that I am at the root directory and I want the list of the etc directory only:
we write,

```
find -type d -name "etc"
```

result we get,

```
[root@unix /]# find -type d -name "etc"

./etc
./usr/lib/firefox/bundled/etc
./usr/lib/unix-yarn/etc
./usr/lib/unix/etc
./usr/lib/festival/etc
./usr/bin/lib/vmware-tools/lib64/libconf/etc
./usr/bin/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libconf/etc
./usr/etc
./usr/share/doc/oddjob-0.30/sample/etc
./usr/share/festival/lib/etc
./usr/local/etc
./usr/java/jdk1.7.0_25/lib/visualvm/etc
./home/user1/Desktop/VMware Tools/vmware-tools-distrib/lib/lib64/libconf/etc
./home/user1/Desktop/VMware Tools/vmware-tools-distrib/lib/lib32/libconf/etc
./home/user1/Desktop/VMware Tools/vmware-tools-distrib/etc
./home/user1/Desktop/VMware Tools/vmware-tools-distrib/caf/etc
```

Another Example,

Also we can write:

```
ls | grep "etc"
```

we get,

```
etc
```