# searching a file

Tags: command-line, search, find, regex

I want to find in the system a file, and I know part name of it. How could I do that? I tried unsuccessfully the command:

```
find / "*partname*"
```

The problem is probably very easy however I cannot find a decent tutorial on searching files in linux. Such one that explains searching in whole system files, in subfolders, recursively, for part of specific expression(s) or excluding. Please tell me what command solves my problem and if you know a good tutorial so that I can understand how to use various parameters for searching, post a link. Thank you so much.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=bash+find+tutorial&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: This is a bit too broad to be answered, even generically. Please make a specific example and we'll be glad to help with that.

Comment: Already answered here: http://askubuntu.com/a/225636/387130

Answer (score 3):

It seems you forgot the -name keyword :

```
find / -name "*partname*"
```

Comment: Yes . . .for better results id use iname flag, since it's case insensitive

Answer (score 1):

Try with `locate` command. Open terminal and write:

```
locate <partname>
```

Comment: If you want to use a locate command you the database of files has to be present. You can create or update the database with `updatedb` and then you can use `locate`.

Comment: Actually, it is: `sudo updatedb`.